# Generating a list of days and passing it through Push.named

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm quite new to flutter and I'm currently working on this mini-project to help me better understand passing data through routes using `push.named` and the `ModalRoute of` method.

**Project Description**:

- *I want to create a list of months and then a list of the days in that month when you tap on it*. Ex: when I tap on January there must be a list of 31 days, February = 29 or 28 depending on whether it's a leap year or not.
- I have been able to generate the list of months but my problem is with the days.

**Requirement**: I used a class to generate the months of the year and I associated a number with each one like this:

```
List<Months> _monthoftheyear =[
    Months(month: "January",id: 1 ),
    Months(month: "February",id: 2),
    Months(month: "March",id: 3),
    Months(month: "April",id: 4),
    Months(month: "May",id: 5),
    Months(month: "June",id: 6),
    Months(month: "July",id: 7),
    Months(month: "August",id: 8),
    Months(month: "September",id: 9),
    Months(month: "October",id: 10),
    Months(month: "November",id: 11),
    Months(month: "December",id: 12),
];
```

What I want to do is use the `id` in a switch statement saying that for case 1,3,5 (months with 31 days) there should be a list of 31 days

```
switch (Months.id){
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    return List.generate(31,(count) "Day $count")
}
```

but I'm trying to do this in my argument parameter in my `Push.named` and later extract it and generate it just like I did with the months it's not working.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? My full code is below

**MY CLASS**

```
class Months {
    String month;
     int id;
      Months ({this.month, this.id});
}
```

```
     **FIRST PAGE**
```

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
    List<Months> _monthoftheyear =[
        Months(month: "January",id: 1 ),
        Months(month: "February",id: 2),
        Months(month: "March",id: 3),
        Months(month: "April",id: 4),
        Months(month: "May",id: 5),
        Months(month: "June",id: 6),
        Months(month: "July",id: 7),
        Months(month: "August",id: 8),
        Months(month: "September",id: 9),
        Months(month: "October",id: 10),
        Months(month: "November",id: 11),
        Months(month: "December",id: 12),
    ];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
      //Listview builder that returns the entirety of the months of the year in a list tile
      body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _monthoftheyear.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(_monthoftheyear[index].month),
          onTap: (){

                 // the argument is that the id should be passed to the next page when the month is 
            tapped on

               // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS. ALL I'M SEEING IS THE "ID" ITSELF AND NOT THE NUMBERS I WANT TO GENERATE. I'm NOT SURE OF WHAT TO DO SO PLEASE PARDON ME IF YOU GET OFFENDED IN ANYWAY
                          


            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/days",arguments: Months (id:_monthoftheyear[index].id));

       setState(() {
      switch (  _monthoftheyear[index].id){
      case 1:
      List.generate(31, (index) => index);
      print(_monthoftheyear[index].id);
      break;

      

       }
      });

          },
        );
        }
      ),

    );
```

THE DETAILS/EXTRACT ARGUMENT PAGE

```
class Days extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final Months _idinfo = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

        return Scaffold(
            body:ListTile(
                title: Text(_idinfo.id.toString()),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will generate DateTime values representing every day of a requested month.  No magic leap year calculations or anything!  You can run it in DartPad to check it out.

```
void main() {
  var year = 2024;
  var month = 2;
  var target = DateTime.utc(year, month);
  var monthBegin = DateTime.utc(target.year, target.month);
//   print(monthBegin);
  var nextMonthBegin = DateTime.utc(monthBegin.year, monthBegin.month + 1);
//   print(nextMonthBegin);
  for (var aDate = monthBegin;
      aDate.isBefore(nextMonthBegin);
      aDate = aDate.add(Duration(days: 1))) {
    print(aDate);
  }
}
```

I use UTC to avoid DST shifts.  Also, that "month + 1" works even for a month of 12... it just wraps back to next year first day of January.  Nice.